# is there a way to know if a TCP Socket is closed by TCPEventBusBridge

Tags: java, vert.x

I have to do some cleanup job on a socket close. I have a TCPEventBusBridge

```
TcpEventBusBridge bridge = TcpEventBusBridge.create(vertx, opts);
bridge.listen(7000, res -> System.out.println("TCP Server Ready"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Vert.x you can use BridgeEventType along with SockJSHandler to detect TCP socket close.

```
  SockJSHandler ebHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(opts , be->{
         if (be.type() == BridgeEventType.PUBLISH  || be.type() == BridgeEventType.RECEIVE) {
               // connection event handling 
            }

         if (be.type() == BridgeEventType.SOCKET_CLOSED ) {
             // close event handling 
         }

         be.complete(Constants.TRUE);
    });
```

Comment: No this doesnt work with TCPEventBridge or Vertx TCP Server. Your example works only for HTTPServer. Infact I modified the library get open and close events for my purpose in Java here https://github.com/sandipsahoo2k2/vertx-tcp-event-bridge